# JavaScript Object literal method: Recursive call

Tags: javascript, recursion, object-literal, function-literal

Is it possible to call recursively a method from an object literal?

For example:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var abc = ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        obj = {
            f: function () {
                if (abc.length) {
                    abc.shift();
                    f(); // Recursive call
                }
            }
        };

    obj.f();
}());
```

Error: 'f' was used before it was defined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

You can, by using a *named function expression*:

```
        f: function myself() {
            if (abc.length) {
                abc.shift();
                myself(); // Recursive call
            }
        }
```

A must-read: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: What exactly does making it a named function do that circumvents the erorr? Create it's own closure?

Answer (score 5):

`f` is a *method* on your object.  As a result, when you're in `f`, `this` will be the object to which `f` is attached.  So to recursively call `f`, use `this.f()`

```
f: function () {
    if (abc.length) {
        abc.shift();
        this.f(); // Recursive call
    }
}
```

---

Just note that inside of `f`, `this` will only be the current object if `f` is invoked as a method: `obj.f();`

If you do somethinig like:  `obj.f.call(lala);`, then `this` will now be `lala`.  And if you do something like:

```
var func = obj.f;
func();
```

Now `this` is the global object inside of `f` (or undefined in strict mode)

Comment: `this` may or may not point to `obj` depending on how `f` is called. Better make this clear before it bites the guy later.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - indeed - edited.  Thanks for the tip, and enjoy your new badges :)

Comment: Yay[!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006587/javascript-object-literal-method-recursive-call)

Answer (score 1):

There's no variable called `f` defined anywhere in your code. Use `obj.f()` (or `this.f` if you know `this` points to where it should).